# How can I create a simple popup for the purposes of giving instructions for my app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I've been searching for a while but I still haven't found really what I need.  I've written a Django app and I want a small dialog box to pop up on each page of my app to provide simple instructions for a new user.  I'm not really familiar in javascript, so the simpler the better.

Comment: Please do some better searching, you can find the concept. After you start and having trouble, you can then post your code so we can tell you where you went wrong. See  [how-to-ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [intro.js](http://introjs.com/) for this sort of thing several times, and have always been happy with the result.